# Cannot use nvidia driver after trying prime-select

Tags: nvidia

I've been using nvidia drivers on 18.04 LTS for quite some time with no issues at all. 
Today I wanted to try the prime-select utility, as my laptoop has dual intel/nvidia GPUs, by issuing:

`prime-select intel`

After rebooting I got a blank screen. So rebooted in recovery-mode and reset with:

`prime-select nvidia`

but rebooting still resulted in blank screen. 
From then I've tried removing (by apt purge) and reinstalling different versions of the nvidia driver but was not able to have it working anymore. 
Any hint what to look at that might be stuck?
I'm assuming this has something to do with the prime-select, but can't figure out what it could cause to permanently affect the graphics card in a way that I am not able to use any nvidia driver anymore. 
Only way to have the screen working is reverting back to the nouveau driver.